# Phonegap - ios9 File input

Tags: javascript, ios, file, cordova, input

I have an issue with phonegap and iOS 9, this was working fine with ios 8, When you click on the file input it shows a cancel button in the middle of the screen that does nothing when tapped. The file input works fine in safari but in my built app, it doesn't.

I realize that there is a phonegap file uploader API, but I am using my app as a web browser to the mobile version of my website, so I haven't built a fully native app, this was a quick solution for me.

This could be because of the new action sheet style or the new option added to the action sheet in ios 9.

Does anyone have a solution that I can skip the action sheet and when clicking the input file I go directly to the camera roll? Or any fix for this?

Comment: Are you using phonegap build or local cordova development? In case you use cordova, which xcode version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I moved to the plugin - [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) and this solved the problem.

After click on input type file:

```
  e.preventDefault();

  navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Please select image', // message
    function (buttonIndex) {
      if (buttonIndex === 1) {
        photoFromSource(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
      } else {
        photoFromSource(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
      }
    },            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Image capture',           // title
    ['Camera', 'Gallery']     // buttonLabels
  );

  function photoFromSource(source) {
    var targetWidth = 640,
      targetHeight = 640,
      onSuccess = function (imageURI) {

        var image = new Image(),
          canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
          canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

        image.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

          self.model.set('imageData', dataURL);
          self.model.setDataAttr('image', true);
          self.render();
        };

        image.src = imageURI;
      },
      onFail = function (message) {
        // Ignore if no image seleted
        if (!/^no image selected$/.test(message))
          alert('Failed because: ' + message);
      },
      opts = {
         quality: 50,
         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         sourceType: source,
         mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
         targetWidth: targetWidth,
         targetHeight: targetHeight,
         encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         correctOrientation: true,
         cameraDirection: navigator.camera.Direction.BACK,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      };

    try {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, opts);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert('Could not capture image: ' + e);
    }
  };
```